# Check if TextBox is empty using JQuery, and prevent postback if so

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How can I check if an asp TextBox is empty on Button click using JQuery, and prevent a postback if so?
It would also be helpful to show an alert dialog asking the user to enter something if it is empty.

So far I have:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtInput" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnOK" Text="OK" onClientClick="return checkInput();" runat="server" />
```

I know the JQuery function should return a true or false, but I don't know how to set the function up or if it should go inside `$(document).ready(function () {});` or not.

Comment: You can do it, but you're mixing technologies.  You'll find over time that it is far easier to use one or the other.  Either use jQuery with HTML or asp: tags but not both together.  Check out the Microsoft MVC framework which is geared to using HTML/JQuery (or knockout.js) on the web pages and then MVC controllers on the back end.  Its a much cleaner, neater solution

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this in Asp.Net I would consider using MVC and its built in validation capabilities instead of creating your own.

You should also add server side validation, but you can leverage the built in MVC client side validators as well

Here's a link with info on how to do it.
http://www.jacopretorius.net/2011/01/client-side-validation-in-mvc-3.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, just put the validate of your textbox into a function:

```
    <script>
        function CheckForm() {
            if ($('#<%=txtInput.ClientID %>').val() == "") {
                alert('Please input');
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    </script>

    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtInput"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="submit" ID="btnSubmit" OnClientClick="return CheckForm()" />
```